# Grandpa leaves the floor wet

Tags: flooring, protection

We have one room whose laminate flooring we need to protect. Grandpa is in there most of the time, it's his bedroom, and he often leaves the floor wet. We need protective covering that we can remove after a couple of years without damaging the underlying surface. Will peel and stick take the finish off the laminate if we remove it after a couple of years? If so, what's a better alternative?

Comment: I would be careful putting down something on an area that is wet.   Yes water on the floor isn't great for laminate but 99% of the time it dries up quickly and there is no harm.   Putting something on top of it invites an area for the floor to stay wet were water is trapped.   You will damage that area.   Once that area is damaged water will get in the floor and seep everywhere else.

Comment: Regular wetting of a laminate floor will damage it after 2 years or so... start saving to replace it. Or prevent / change what is causing the wetting - does he walk out of the shower wet?

Comment: Perhaps a bed pan and Depends would alleviate some of the problem.  Make sure you don't put anything down that can be tripped over.  Falls are hard on the elderly.

Comment: I’ve never used it and don’t know much about it, so I’m not posting this an answer since I can’t actually recommend it. But have a look at loose-lay sheet vinyl flooring. https://www.bhg.com/home-improvement/flooring/installation-how-to/how-to-install-loose-lay-sheet-vinyl/ If you go this route, be very careful about where the seams are since that is where you will get the most water intrusion. If grandpa is making tsunamis in the bathtub, no temporary flooring solution will help, but if its the occasional small spill, something like this might work.